# How to run elasticsearch server in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, elasticsearch

Running on Linux Mint 16, I followed this guide here: http://pivotallabs.com/rspec-elasticsearchruby-elasticsearchmodel/ to setup elasticsearch with Ruby on Rails application.

When I run rspec, when it hits this line spec_helper.rb:

```
config.before :each, elasticsearch: true do
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.start(port: 9200) unless Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?
  end
```

I received the following error:

*Starting 2 Elasticsearch nodes..sh: 1: elasticsearch: not found*

**I thought it might be a path issue....**

So I added the following to ~/.bashrc:

*export PATH="/etc/init.d:$PATH"*  since *sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start* starts the elasticsearch service.

Then I issued command *source ~/.bashrc*

This got rid of the *sh: 1: elasticsearch: not found* message and instead the message from the error triggered in spec_helper.rb was:

```
............Starting 2 Elasticsearch nodes..
[!!!] Process failed to start (see output above)
F........
```

Below is the config block in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
config.before :each, elasticsearch: true do
    Article.__elasticsearch__.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: 'http://localhost:9200'
    Article.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)
    Article.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.start(port: 9200) unless Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?
  end

  config.after :suite do
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.stop(port: 9200) if Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?
  end
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

EDIT: If I change to port 9250 as suggested by commenter below:

```
config.before :each, elasticsearch: true do
   Article.__elasticsearch__.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: 'http://localhost:9250'
    Article.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)
    Article.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.start(port: 9250) unless Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?
  end

  config.after :suite do
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.stop(port: 9250) if Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?
  end
```

I get this new error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
    Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9250
    occurred at /home/nona/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'

F........
```

Comment: Do you already have Elasticsearch running outside of the test? I see you checking but does that check for any instance of Elasticsearch already running or just whatever the test helper is doing to track its own cluster? Try changing the port to 9250 and see if that causes it to start without issue.

Comment: Thanks MattC, the new error is up above - but I think it's because elasticsearch is still running on 9200...if I navigate to http://localhost:9200/ in my browser I get a 200 status.

Comment: Hey @Nona, have you solved the problem? It's happening with me right now and surprisingly, I can't find a solution online

Comment: Hey @AlexandreWiechersVaz, found this link via Ruby Weekly 233: http://www.binarywebpark.com/testing-elasticsearch-in-your-rails-4-application/

Answer (score 3):

I remember having a similar problem, and I solved it with the following line in my test_helper:

```
ENV["TEST_CLUSTER_NODES"] = "1" # need to set so we trigger correct ES defaults
```

I figured it out by looking at the `Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster` source and realizing that `Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.running?` was returning `true` (and therefore not starting the cluster) unless that TEST_CLUSTER_NODES value is set.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it sparked some ideas; I tried this but the only thing different that happens is that I get a message "..Starting 1 Elasticsearch nodes."  If I pop into a debugging environment, returns false